# C# - Executing and Determining Class Calls Dynamically

Tags: c#, database, class, generics, dynamic

I am trying to create an application that will dynamically generate inline SQL query statements and pass back various objects. Each object class I have created has a IRowMapper< ObjectName > GetMapping method.

I execute the the SQL and generate the object result list with the following command, for my example I will use a Person object:

```
result.List = new List<Object>(db.ExecuteSqlStringAccessor<Person>(sql, Person.GetMapping()).ToList());
```

However, I will have several different object return type, not just Person. I am wondering if it is possible to dynamically get the class from a string and call the ExecuteSQLStringAccessor. For example, something like this:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("MyClass", true);

result.List = new List<Object>(db.ExecuteSqlStringAccessor<type>(SSUDBHelper.OpenQueryRequest(sql, assoc), type.GetMapping()).ToList());
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

***Update***

Can I make this:

```
result.List = new List<Object>(db.ExecuteSqlStringAccessor<Person>(sql, Person.GetMapping()).ToList());

result.List = new List<Object>(db.ExecuteSqlStringAccessor<Company>(sql, Company.GetMapping()).ToList());

result.List = new List<Object>(db.ExecuteSqlStringAccessor<Invoice>(sql, Invoice.GetMapping()).ToList());
```

generic?

Comment: You can use a base class that all your models implement and make the base class (or interface) have the method GetMapping. Or use the type to Invoke a method through reflection. Lastly you can use dynamic and call it from there.

Comment: Do `Person`, `Company` and `Invoice` share a common interface that specifies the `GetMapping` member?

Comment: Also, you can cast using `db.ExecuteSqlStringAccessor<Invoice>(sql, Invoice.GetMapping()).Cast<object>().ToList()` instead of what you're doing now.

Comment: @Asad No, `Person`, `Company` and `Invoice` do not have a common interface. They each only have their own `IRowMapper<className> GetMapping()` methods. The objects and class were setup by someone else and I can't make many modification to the existing classes or structure.

Comment: @ThreadedLemon Okay, so then you have to use `dynamic`. I'll put this in an answer.

Comment: @Asad Thanks! That would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @ThreadedLemon Ah, I completely missed the fact that `GetMapping` is a static method! Unfortunately the dynamic approach won't work here. We can use reflection to do this instead. Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `GetMapping` is a static method, we have no choice but to use reflection to have it resolved at runtime:

```
IEnumerable<T> GetAsListOf<T>(string sql, YourDBType db) {
    IRowMapper<T> mapper = (IRowMapper<T>)typeof(T).GetMethod("GetMapping").Invoke(null, null);
    return db.ExecuteSqlStringAccessor<T>(sql, mapper);
}
```

Comment: I am still fairly new to the whole idea of reflection. Should I just be calling this like `GetAsListOf<type>(sql, db);`? It says the type or namespace 'type' cannot be found.

Comment: @ThreadedLemon You're not supposed to literally use the type argument `type`. You can do `GetAsListOf<Person>(sql, db)`, and it'll give you an `IEnumerable<Person>`.

Comment: Ah, okay...but if I don't know it'll be a `Person` type until runtime, can I not do something like `Type type = Type.GetType(dataType, true);` where dataType is a string of either "Person", "Invoice" or "Company"?

Comment: @ThreadedLemon Okay, so basically you want to have the type as some instantiated `System.Type` that you've gotten from `typeof` or otherwise, and you want to go from that to an `IEnumerable` of the type, retrieved from the database. Is that correct?

Comment: @ThreadedLemon Okay, so assuming your `Type` instance is in `MyType`: in order to invoke this `GetAsListOf` method you need to do this: `MethodInfo method = typeof(this).GetMethod("GetAsListOf");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(myType);
var result = generic.Invoke(this, new object[] {sql, db});`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70086/discussion-between-threadedlemon-and-asad).